# cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans' - applicationcontext.xml

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

I end up getting only this error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 12 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
I see that there is a declaration for beans already present

Can someone help me with where I am exactly going wrong?

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemalocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Spring jar present is 4.1.6.

Comment: There is a missing **>**

Comment: If only it was that simple. it was my bad copy pasting from the outside machine. It does have a > in the source, but i still get the same error . Thanks for catching that here. I will edit the question

Comment: Can you show us at least 12 lines ? The error looks like to occur on line 12

Comment: @Alexandre Jacob : I just updated my question with the applicationContext file as is. Please let em know if you see anything wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your corrected file :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
</beans>
```

You wrote `xsi:schemalocation` instead of `xsi:schemaLocation` (note the uppercase **L**)

Answer (score 0):

More information about the `xsi:schemaLocation`:

The XML parser will read the schema location from internet and use it to validate the xml. If you do not have internet access (as do most Productive systems with no out going internet access) Spring comes to the rescue. It interprets the read requests and loads the schema from within the Spring jars.